# How to return the number of edges and nodes using a select statement with traverse?

Tags: sql, nodes, orientdb, graph-databases

I'm running this query

```
select * from (traverse both() FROM #33:0 WHILE $depth < 1) WHERE 
          @class = 'L'
```

How can I display the number of nodes and edges of the results of that query?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `count(*)`:

This counts the vertices:

```
 select count(*) from (traverse both() FROM #33:0 WHILE $depth < 1) 
 WHERE $this instanceof V
```

This counts the edges

```
 select count(*) from (traverse bothE(), bothV() FROM #33:0 WHILE $depth < 1) 
 WHERE $this instanceof E
```

Comment: I'm getting 0 as a result yet it is not the case